# Handling Multiple Databases in Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working on a fairly large project at the moment and there is data that I'm wanting to be stored in a different database. how would I handle that in laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, you can do things like:

```
User::connection('another-connection-name')->where('email', 'john@doe.com')->first();
```

In Laravel, switching to a different database connection at any time.

Here's also a post about this: http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections

Comment: Ahh it all makes sense now :) Thanks